# PHP error "parameter was not defined"

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying with one friend to make a simple upload form, but i'm stuck at the moment. Here's my trouble :

I made this form:

[image: screenshot]

This is the code :

```
<form method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="../i/insert.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Title</label>
        <div class="col-lg-10">
            <input name="v" id="title" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Banana nation">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Uploader's name</label>
        <div class="col-lg-10">
            <input name="name" id="upname" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Onision">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Description</label>
        <div class="col-lg-10">
            <textarea name="description" id="description" class="form-control" rows="3" placeholder="We are not robots, we are not slaves, we are banana nation."></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputFile" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Video thumbnail</label>
        <div class="col-lg-10">
            <input type="file" id="thumbnail" name="thumbnail">
            <p class="help-block">Click to upload your file.</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-10">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

This form have an action to `../i/insert.php`, here's the code (`insert.php`):

```
<?php
require('db.php');


    $dossier = '/var/www/vids/m/';
    $file = basename($_FILES['thumbnail']['name']);
    $thmb_name = basename($_FILES['thumbnail']['name']);
    $taille_maxi = 3145728;
    $taille = filesize($_FILES['thumbnail']['tmp_name']);
    $extensions = array('.png', '.jpg', '.jpeg');
    $extension = strrchr($_FILES['thumbnail']['name'], '.'); 

    if(!in_array($extension, $extensions)) 
    {
         $erreur = 'You can only upload a png, jpg or a jpeg file.';
    }
    if($taille>$taille_maxi)
    {
         $erreur = 'Hng.. it\'s too big sen-senpai.., it must be smaller than 3 mb...';
    }
    if(!isset($erreur))
    {

         $file = strtr($file, 
              'ÀÁÂÃÄÅÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÒÓÔÕÖÙÚÛÜÝàáâãäåçèéêëìíîïðòóôõöùúûüýÿ', 
              'AAAAAACEEEEIIIIOOOOOUUUUYaaaaaaceeeeiiiioooooouuuuyy');
         $file = preg_replace('/([^.a-z0-9]+)/i', '-', $file);
         if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['thumbnail']['tmp_name'], $dossier . $file))
         {
              $thmb_result = 'Upload succesfull !';
         }
         else
         {
              $thmb_result = 'Upload failed !';
         }
    }
ajout($_POST['v'], $_POST['name'], $_POST['description'], $_POST['description'], $file);
function ajout($v, $name, $description, $fichier, $file)
    {
        global $bdd;
        $req = $bdd->prepare('INSERT INTO `vids`.`vidinfos` (`v`, `name`, `date`, `description`, `fichier`, `file`, `id`) VALUES (:v, :name, CURRENT_DATE(), :description, :fichier, :file, NULL);');
        $req->execute(array(
        ':v' => $v,
        ':name' => $name,
        ':description' => $description,
        ':fichier' => $fichier,
        ':thmb_name' => $file
        ));
    }
$bdd->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

And here's database structure:
[image]

So I fill up the form, and the picture successfully uploads in the directory I requested, but nothing shows up in my database, no new entry. I checked that every variable is correctly defined using `var_dump`.

Plus, I got this error in my PHP error log:

```
[Wed Jul 09 15:57:52 2014] [error] [client 10.0.0.1] PHP Warning:  PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined on line 48
```

Comment: Just paste the actual code. The editor shows you how to do this – highlight the code and click on the `{}` icon. Also when pasting links, include the protocol (`http://`) so that they are converted into links that we don't have to copy-and-paste.

Comment: @CharlieS I couldn't post more than 4 links and pictures, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your parameters do not match -> `:file` != `:thmb_name`

```
$req = $bdd->prepare('INSERT INTO `vids`.`vidinfos` (`v`, `name`, `date`, `description`, `fichier`, `file`, `id`) VALUES (:v, :name, CURRENT_DATE(), :description, :fichier, **:file**, NULL);');

$req->execute(array(
    ':v' => $v,
    ':name' => $name,
    ':description' => $description,
    ':fichier' => $fichier,
    '**:thmb_name**' => $file
    ));
```

Should be

```
$req->execute(array(
    ':v' => $v,
    ':name' => $name,
    ':description' => $description,
    ':fichier' => $fichier,
    ':file' => $file
    ));
```

Comment: @IbrahimAshShohail, true, I added them for emphasis, but for clarity removed it from the correct parameter.

Answer (score 3):

You're specifying a parameter `file` but are binding it as `thmb_name`. They should be the same parameter.